# two same jquery plugins execute simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like a little help here. I have two jquery sliders but i would like them to run at the same time. Is it possible?

Here is my code :

```
$(function () {
    $('#slider').camera({
        autoAdvance: true,
        height: 'auto',
        loader: 'none',
        navigation: false,
        pagination: false,
        thumbnails: false,
        fx: 'scrollHorz',
        time: 3000,
        playPause: false
    });
    $('#slider_small').camera({
        autoAdvance: true,
        height: 'auto',
        loader: 'none',
        navigation: false,
        pagination: false,
        thumbnails: false,
        fx: 'scrollHorz',
        time: 3000,
        playPause: false
    });
});
```

with the above code the second start after some milliseconds. I would appreciate if someone can fix it.

Comment: *second start after some milliseconds* - use ```setTimeout```

Comment: @MichalStefanow: I think the goal is for that *not* to happen.

Answer (score 0):

As those options are identical, I'd think

```
$("#slider, #slider_small").camera({
    /* ...options here... */
});
```

would do it. Properly-designed jQuery plugins understand they're working on sets of elements.

Comment: I 've tried it but it doesnt work. Any other solution?

Comment: @DMande: If the plugin doesn't support linking the elements together, then no, probably not -- using that plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $('#slider, #slider_small').camera({
        autoAdvance: true,
        height: 'auto',
        loader: 'none',
        navigation: false,
        pagination: false,
        thumbnails: false,
        fx: 'scrollHorz',
        time: 3000,
        playPause: false
    });
});
```

most standard JQuery plugins knows to accepts an array of elements, and with `,` in the selector you can select multiple elements.

p.s. the plugin most probably will use for-each so what's the real problem here? if its just jumping then maybe your solution is css?